# Angular - How to dynamically pass environment values inside forRoot in the app.module?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, inject

I would like to pass values taken from the related environment file (env.json) in  the **app.module** but these values are not available at the moment of the initialization of the GtmModule (are available several ms after initialization).

I would like to ask which approach should be used to achieve values. I tried @Inject and custom Factory but without luck.

```
GtmModule.forRoot({
      debug:environment.gaAnalyticsDebug,
      disabled:environment.gaAnalyticsDisabled, // GETTING UNDEFINED HERE
      gtmId: 'XXXX',
      readExtIdCookie: false,
    }),
```

Comment: did you replace angular.json file too?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate environment files :

environment.staging.ts :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  gaAnalyticsDebug: 'https://api.staging.com',
  gaAnalyticsDisabled:true
};
```

In your angular.json file :

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  },
  "staging": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

In your app.module.ts :

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GtmModule.forRoot({
     debug:environment.gaAnalyticsDebug,
     disabled:environment.gaAnalyticsDisabled, // GETTING UNDEFINED HERE
     gtmId: 'XXXX',
     readExtIdCookie: false,
   }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I have already separed json files 
env.int.json
env.json
env.prep.json
env.prod.json

Which are handled by following method in main.ts file.

fetch(ENV_FILENAME)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((env) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE', env);
    setEnvironment(env);
    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }

    platformBrowserDynamic()
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });

Some approach to how to handle it async way?